# Newly added XML column with default xml value always shows NULL

Tags: sql-server

I'm running the command

```
ALTER TABLE [DB].dbo.TABLEA ADD [Field1] [xml]  DEFAULT
CAST(N'<SettingValues xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://someurl.com/schemas.xsd" />' AS xml)
```

I was expecting a new column show up with the xml string but instead they are all showing NULL.
Did I do something wrong?

I based my syntax on this [Microsoft document resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/create-xml-data-type-variables-and-columns?view=sql-server-ver15).

You can test this out over at the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6ccb2/1) I created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default only applies to newly added rows. You will have to do an `UPDATE` to set the existing rows to the desired default.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  My reason of doing this in the first place is the table has over 90 million rows, I was trying to avoid the update which takes long and produce ungodly amount of transaction logs.

Answer (score 4):

When creating the new column you can use the SQL Server [WITH VALUES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-column-definition-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) syntax to have the default value set.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
    ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
    TestData VARCHAR(120)
);

INSERT TableA Select 'A';
INSERT TableA Select 'B';
INSERT TableA Select 'C';

SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    TableA;
```

Running the above produce the following output.

```
ID  TestData
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

We then add two new columns, Field1 and Field2 using the following syntax

```
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD [Field1] [xml]  DEFAULT
CAST(N'<SettingValues xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://someurl.com/schemas.xsd" />' AS xml) 


ALTER TABLE TableA ADD [Field2] [xml]  DEFAULT
CAST(N'<SettingValues xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://someurl.com/schemas.xsd" />' AS xml) WITH VALUES
```

The following desired result is obtained for the new column Field2 with the existing rows populated with the XMLstring while those for new column Field1 are Null.

```
ID  TestData    Field1  Field2
1   A   NULL    <SettingValues xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://someurl.com/schemas.xsd" />
2   B   NULL    <SettingValues xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://someurl.com/schemas.xsd" />
3   C   NULL    <SettingValues xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://someurl.com/schemas.xsd" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If the column is set to `NOT NULL` then the default value is used even if `WITH VALUES` is not used.

```sql
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD [Field3] [xml]  NOT NULL DEFAULT
CAST(N'<SettingValues xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://someurl.com/schemas.xsd" />' AS xml)
```

[From the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-column-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> When adding a column *and* a `DEFAULT` constraint, if the column allows `NULLS` using `WITH VALUES` will, for existing rows, set the new column's value to the value given in `DEFAULT` *constant_expression*. **If the column being added does not allow `NULLS`, for existing rows, the column's value will always be set to the value given in the `DEFAULT` *constant expression*.**

[This fiddle demonstrates the difference.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=68bf2d6a94f91fe314f8603f8f8296cb)